# Existence of closed-form solution or feasible numerical solution to a special case of Ricatti equation

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

Sorry if this is a duplicate. I am trying to implement a symplectic scheme (right now symplectic Euler, but the same problem shows up for more advanced schemes as well) for a matrix ODE (i.e. the variables are square, symmetric and positive definite matrices), and in one of the steps a matrix equation of the form
$$
X_{i+1}=X_{i}-hX_{i+1}Y_{i}X_{i+1}
$$
shows up, where $h$ is a (small) real number and we solve for $X_{i+1}$ . I recognize that this is a particular case of a Ricatti equation, but any solver I try fails to find a solution after a few steps. So I wonder:

Bonus zeroth question: Can I even be sure that a theoretical solution exists?

A) Is there a closed-form solution?

B) If not, can I hope for this equation to be numerically solvable at all?

Best regards!